# Neo4j find path between nodes with multiple hops and same pattern

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

i have a neo4j graph that pictures a transportation system.

My nodes are:

- Stop (like a bus stop)
- Connection (connection node between 2 stops)

Relationships:

- `(Stop)-[:HAS]->(Connection)-[:TO]->(Stop)`

My problem is that this pattern might repeat multiple times like this:

- `(Stop)-[:HAS]->(Connection)-[:TO]->(Stop)-[:HAS]->(Connection)-[:TO]->(Stop)-[:HAS]->(Connection)-[:TO]->(Stop)`

I would like to have a cypher query with that i can find a connection between 2 stops even if there are multiple `-[:HAS]->(Connection)-[:TO]->` steps between them.

I tried

```
MATCH (:Stop)-[:HAS]->(:Connection)-[:TO]->(:Stop)
```

but with this i only get results with only 1 hop. I hope my question is understandable.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only types of nodes between :Stops are :Connections then I think this will get you what you need:

```
   MATCH (from:Stop)-[:HAS|TO*1..5]-(to:Stop)
   WHERE ...
```

From a schema perspective, though, you may want to consider replacing `(:Stop)-[:HAS]->(:Connection)-[:T0]->(:Stop)` with just a single relationship: `(:Stop)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(:Stop)`